# Unable to parse logstash.yml file within /etc/logstash [ELK Stack]

Tags: elasticsearch, yaml, logstash, logstash-configuration

Good Evening,

I receive the error: unable to parse logstash.yml

My OS: lubuntu 20.04.3

Here is the uncommented line of code within the `etc/logstash/logstash.yml`

```
path.conf: "/etc/logstash/conf.d"
```

Within the conf.d directory, I have my `logstash.conf file`
I run the command using: /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f, --path.settings /etc/logstash`

Here is the whole logstash.yml file: https://pastebin.com/gTk1Cuhc

I've tried:

```
path.conf: /etc/logstash/conf.d
```

and

```
path.conf: '/etc/logstash/conf.d'
```

Comment: Hi, the path.conf setting does not exist (but path.config does) ;-) (source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-settings-file.html )

Comment: @lmsec Oops, that was a typo in my post. However, now it says it cannot parse my config file. I will update my post accordingly